# Calculating days between certain dates with certain days being excluded using java Calendar

Tags: java

I'm trying to come up with a way to calculate the number of days between two different dates, however there will be certain days of the week that are only to be accounted for. For example, let's say we want to calculate the number of work days between 8/1 and 8/31, but employee only works Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday. The result would be that this employee only works 15 days during that period.

Has anyone put together something similar using the java Calendar class?

Comment: Just a tip: Be very, very careful doing this, assume nothing, and find an accountant to test it for you and see if it makes sense. Programmers are logical creatures, and accountants + the tax code are not logical. There are lots of things that can go wrong.

Comment: What if one of the Mondays, Tuesdays or Wednesdays in that month is a bank/public holiday?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), is the best solution to manage Date and Time.

The code of **dogbane** corrected:

```
    final Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
    current.set(2011, 7, 1);

    final Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    end.set(2011, 7, 31);
    int count = 0;
    while (!current.after(end)) {
        int dayOfWeek = current.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.MONDAY || 
            dayOfWeek == Calendar.TUESDAY || 
            dayOfWeek == Calendar.WEDNESDAY) {
            count++;
        }
        current.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

If use **Joda Time**:

```
    DateTime current = new DateTime(2011, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(2011, 8, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    int count = 0;
    while (!current.isAfter(end)) {

        int dayOfWeek = current.getDayOfWeek();
        if (dayOfWeek == DateTimeConstants.MONDAY || dayOfWeek == DateTimeConstants.TUESDAY
                || dayOfWeek == DateTimeConstants.WEDNESDAY) {
            count++;
        }
        current = current.plusDays(1);
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: However put in 8/1 to 8/31, should return 15 as well but for some reason returns 12. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't appear 7/1/2011 is getting set correctly. July 1st should be a Friday (6) however the java calendar thinks it's Monday(2). I'm not familiar with Joda Time, how might I make this work using that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by incrementing the date by one day until you reach the end date. At each iteration, check if the day is Mon, Tue or Wed and increment a counter.

For example:

```
final Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
current.set(2011, 7, 1);

final Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
end.set(2011, 7, 31);

int count = 0;
while (current.compareTo(end) != 0) {
    current.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    int dayOfWeek = current.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.MONDAY || 
        dayOfWeek == Calendar.TUESDAY || 
        dayOfWeek == Calendar.WEDNESDAY) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Your output is 14, while Jeff expects 15.

Comment: Yes, I know. Jeff should be able to tweak it to make it "inclusive" of the starting date.

Comment: In our version of oracle java.version 1.4.2_06
I'm getting the following error.

Error(28,20): method compareTo(java.util.Calendar) not found in class java.util.Calendar

Answer (score 0):

You could roll your own solution with java.util.Calendar; however, I suggest looking at some existing library, such as [ObjectLab Kit](http://objectlabkit.sourceforge.net/) date utilities.